# Let $T:V_3 \to V_2$ be a linear transformation. Calculate $T(x,y,z)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V_3 \to V_2$ be a linear transformation which matrix is:

$$A= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$

relative to the basis $\{(1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)\}$ of $ V_3;$ And $ \{(1,1), (1,-1)\}$ of $V_2$

Calculate $T(x,y,z)$.

---

I have started, using the matrix $A$  to write the transformation of the vectors of $V_3$

$$T(1,0,0)=(2)(1,1)+(1)(1,-1)=(3,1)$$
$$T(1,1,0)=(1)(1,1)+(0)(1,-1)=(1,1)$$
$$T(1,1,1)=(0)(1,1)+(-1)(1,-1)=(-1,1)$$

But i dont know how to calculate the transformation.

Comment: what is A here in the question?

Comment: The matrix of the linear transformation relative to the descripted basis

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $T(x,y,z)=x\cdot T(1,0,0) + y\cdot T(0,1,0) + z\cdot T(0,0,1)$.

Can you compute $T(1,0,0)$, $T(0,1,0)$ and $T(0,0,1)$?

Comment: should i use that $T(1,0,0)=(3,1)$ and the other transformation for the compute?

Comment: @VictorFranciscoSalazarGarci, of course you need to use what is given to you. So yes $T(1,0,0)=(3,1)$, and $T(0,1,0)=T(1,1,0)-T(1,0,0)=(1,1)-(3,1)=(-2,0)$ etc.